# Is there any way to control JSON formatting with the WCF Web API?

Tags: .net, json, rest, formatting, wcf-web-api

With the upcoming [WCF Web API](http://wcf.codeplex.com/), is there any way to control JSON output?

I'd like to change the casing and perhaps suppress that certain properties are included when a class is being serialized.

As an example, consider this very simply class:

```
[XmlRoot("catalog", Namespace = "http://api.247e.com/catalog/2012")]
public class Catalog
{
    [XmlArray(ElementName = "link-templates")]
    public LinkTemplate[] LinkTemplates { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see, I've added various XML attributes to it in order to control how it's serialized in XML. Can I do the same (or something else) for JSON?

For reference, here's a sample output in XML:

```
<catalog xmlns="http://api.247e.com/catalog/2012"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <link-templates>
        <link-template href="http://localhost:9000/search/?criterion={criterion}"
                       rel="http://docs.247e.com/rels/search"/>
    </link-templates>
</catalog>
```

For JSON, the equivalent result is this:

```
{
  "LinkTemplates":
  [
    {
      "Href":"http:\/\/localhost:9000\/search\/?criterion={criterion}",
      "Rel":"http:\/\/docs.247e.com\/rels\/search"
    }
  ]
}
```

However, I'd like to change the casing of the properties, so I'd prefer something like this instead:

```
{
  "linkTemplates":
  [
    {
      "href":"http:\/\/localhost:9000\/search\/?criterion={criterion}",
      "rel":"http:\/\/docs.247e.com\/rels\/search"
    }
  ]
}
```

A way to strip away certain class properties would also be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WCF Web API used the DataContractJsonSerializer by default to return a resource in a JSON format. So you should be using the DataContract and DataMember attributes on you class to shape the JSON result.

```
[DataContract]
public class Book
{
    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    [DataMember(Name = "author")]
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [XmlIgnore] // Don't send this one
    public string ImageName { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the JSON.NET Formatter from the WCF Web API Contrib project on codeplex. Attributes like shown here should help you https://json.svn.codeplex.com/svn/trunk/Doc/SerializationAttributes.html

Answer (score 1):

JSON.NET has several attribute options which can control what is serialized and how. http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/